# Prove that the cyclic group of order 4, $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ is indecomposable.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can someone please explain how I can show it is not indecomposable. I know I have to show it cannot be split into two different non-zero sets. Is it enough to say that the Lagrangian theorem says that its subsets can only have sets with cardinality of 1, 2 or 4?

Comment: It is enough...if you can explain why it is enough.

Comment: I think you mean `indecomposable` instead of `not indecomposable`.

Comment: Is it enough because it is not isomorphic to its subgroup?

Comment: How many non-trivial subgroups does $\;\Bbb Z_4\;$ have?

Comment: 3, 4 if you count its self?

Comment: Am i correct to say that the subgroups have order, 1,2,2?

Answer (score 1):

If $\mathbb Z_4$ were decomposable, it'd be a product of two groups of order $2$, but every element in this product has order at most $2$ and there are no elements of order $4$.

A quite similar argument works for $\mathbb Z_n$ when $n$ is prime power. These are exactly the indecomposable cyclic groups.

Comment: since $4 = 2 \cdot 2$ is the only nontrivial factorization of $4$

Comment: @AlexVong, exactly! Good point.